# Postgres force fire trigger on foreign key table

Tags: postgresql

```
Table fk_parent

id integer,
amount numeric,
account_id int,

Table fk_child
id integer,
fk_parent_id integer,
amount numeric
```

I have an after update trigger on fk_parent which deletes rows in another table (a different module) and inserts data afresh which includes data from fk_child too.

Any update of fk_child does not fire the trigger on fk_parent when fk_parent is not saved simultaneously.

Is there any way by which I can force the trigger on update of fk_child if fk_parent is not being updated in the *`same transaction`*.

As there are deletes I want to fire the trigger as little time as possible.

I am using Postgres 12.0

Thanks

Comment: This is functionality that might be best moved back into the app and out of triggers; triggers are notoriously poor business rule enforces.  You cannot force a DML trigger to fire, they only fire when the table+event they defined on occurs. However, Postgres triggers  just execute a procedure (well actually a function). And, while not the most recommended,  multiple triggers can call the same trigger function or the trigger functions can each call a common function. Your logic could get very tricky but it could be done.